# How to configure Corda network using docker (using YAML file)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, corda

I'm struggling to configure my Corda network (which is really similar to `https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example`) using docker, I'm just missing examples with a real network like [this](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example), load cordapps is easy (all examples I found so far loads and yo sample like this one: `https://github.com/corda/corda-docker/tree/master/plugins`), but commit the transaction is something totally different (shouldn't be hard, I agree!).

In order to commit the transaction, consensus in the network and notary approval are needed, and if nodes in the network are not communicating both requirements are not possible.

I'm getting these logs from Xxxxx node when I try to commit a transation to the ledger **(As you can see the transaction is mapped to reach localhost:10010 instead of expected xxxxxx:10010)**:

```js
[WARN ] 2018-09-20T20:47:03,246Z [main] utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.set - Double insert in net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMap for entity class class net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$PersistentIdentity key E66540FF121D732F4417B293203D1C61F9F5A467A19AC21EE0327665BA0CA561, not inserting the second time {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:03,257Z [main] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.updateBridgesOnNetworkChange - Updating bridges on network map change: NodeInfo(addresses=[xxxxx:10002], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537476408266) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:03,465Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Loaded CorDapps                         : example-cordapp-0.1, corda-finance-3.2-corda, corda-core-3.2-corda {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:03,481Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Node for "Xxxxx" started up and registered in 55.5 sec {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:03,486Z [main] messaging.RPCServer.start - Starting RPC server with configuration RPCServerConfiguration(rpcThreadPoolSize=4, reapInterval=PT1S, deduplicationCacheExpiry=PT24H) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:04,278Z [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - SUBMITTING {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=df81b170-c57d-4d2c-ac5e-c50b2dbc951d, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:47:04.249Z, session_id=84058489-40f2-4b91-9527-8e0cfe188294, session_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:46:55.554Z}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:07,901Z [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - SUBMITTING {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=abaaafe5-91a9-450f-9b04-078c4446697d, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:47:07.901Z, session_id=84058489-40f2-4b91-9527-8e0cfe188294, session_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:46:55.554Z}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:08,572Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10010], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381493186) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:08,660Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - No previous node found {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:08,938Z [RxIoScheduler-2] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.updateBridgesOnNetworkChange - Updating bridges on network map change: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10010], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381493186) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,053Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Done adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10010], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381493186) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,053Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10013], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381494853) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,056Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - No previous node found {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,138Z [RxIoScheduler-2] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.updateBridgesOnNetworkChange - Updating bridges on network map change: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10013], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381494853) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,161Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Done adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10013], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381494853) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,161Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10007], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381494948) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,237Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Discarding older nodeInfo for O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,237Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10006], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381495396) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,263Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - No previous node found {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,347Z [RxIoScheduler-2] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.updateBridgesOnNetworkChange - Updating bridges on network map change: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10006], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381495396) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:47:09,358Z [RxIoScheduler-2] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode - Done adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10006], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary, L=New York, C=US], platformVersion=3, serial=1537381495396) {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:56,465Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - SUBMITTING {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=bb90b749-06e8-4f8d-9ef1-b841d0e7be8e, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:55:56.465Z, session_id=84058489-40f2-4b91-9527-8e0cfe188294, session_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:46:55.554Z}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:56,529Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - SUBMITTING {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=3b9a0d1b-309f-4a08-bd6d-2e332ac7e069, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:55:56.529Z, session_id=84058489-40f2-4b91-9527-8e0cfe188294, session_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:46:55.554Z}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:57,251Z [Node thread-1] flow.[8429c030-3a58-4c1a-985c-64eca7f4c54e].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=Xxxxxx, L=New York, C=US. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=8801945676362020052). {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:57,371Z [Messaging DLGWNKZHEid91BXSUY1sSxtGkcoJRjwy3NCrXHXWzsxcNU] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.createQueueIfAbsent - Create fresh queue internal.peers.DL6ZbP6hVmkL3w2rysrMYHchy7axULJssDPkjUzxvn9DB6 bound on same address {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:57,439Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] bridging.BridgeControlListener.processControlMessage - Received bridge control message Create(nodeIdentity=DLGWNKZHEid91BXSUY1sSxtGkcoJRjwy3NCrXHXWzsxcNU, bridgeInfo=BridgeEntry(queueName=internal.peers.DL6ZbP6hVmkL3w2rysrMYHchy7axULJssDPkjUzxvn9DB6, targets=[localhost:10010], legalNames=[O=Xxxxxx, L=New York, C=US])) {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=3b9a0d1b-309f-4a08-bd6d-2e332ac7e069, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:55:56.529Z, session_id=84058489-40f2-4b91-9527-8e0cfe188294, session_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:46:55.554Z}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:57,462Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] peers.DL6ZbP6hVmkL3w2rysrMYHchy7axULJssDPkjUzxvn9DB6 -> localhost:10010:O=Xxxxxx, L=New York, C=US.start - Create new AMQP bridge {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=3b9a0d1b-309f-4a08-bd6d-2e332ac7e069, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:55:56.529Z, session_id=84058489-40f2-4b91-9527-8e0cfe188294, session_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:46:55.554Z}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:57,474Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] netty.AMQPClient.start - connect to: localhost:10010 {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=Xxxxx, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=3b9a0d1b-309f-4a08-bd6d-2e332ac7e069, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:55:56.529Z, session_id=84058489-40f2-4b91-9527-8e0cfe188294, session_timestamp=2018-09-20T20:46:55.554Z}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:57,569Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:58,571Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:58,574Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:59,576Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:55:59,580Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-5] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:00,582Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-6] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:00,589Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-7] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:01,591Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-8] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:01,593Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:02,595Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:02,599Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:03,600Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:03,603Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-5] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:04,604Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-6] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:04,606Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-7] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:05,607Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-8] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:05,610Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:06,612Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:06,614Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:07,616Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:07,618Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-5] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:08,620Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-6] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to localhost:10010 {}
[INFO ] 2018-09-20T20:56:08,623Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-7] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to localhost:10010 {}
```

This is a node.conf file related to one of my nodes (all the others are in same format):

```js
myLegalName="O=Xxxxx,L=New York,C=US"
basedir : "/opt/corda"
p2pAddress : "xxxxx:10002"
webAddress : "xxxxx:10004"
rpcSettings {
    useSsl=false
    address="xxxxx:10003"
    adminAddress="xxxxx:10051"
}
keyStorePassword : "cordacadevpass"
trustStorePassword : "trustpass"
h2port : 11000
useHTTPS : false
devMode : true
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
```

This is the notary node.conf file:

```js
basedir : "/opt/corda"
p2pAddress : "notary:10002"
webAddress : "notary:10004"
h2port : 11000
myLegalName="O=Notary,L=New York,C=US"
detectPublicIp=false
keyStorePassword : "cordacadevpass"
trustStorePassword : "trustpass"
extraAdvertisedServiceIds: [ "corda.notary.simple" ]
useHTTPS : false
devMode : true
rpcSettings = {
  useSsl=false
  address="notary:10003"
  adminAddress="notary:10052"
}
notary {
    validating=false
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
```

This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```js
version: '3.3'
services:

  Notary:
    networks:
    - corda
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION: 3.2-corda
    env_file:
    - ./corda_docker.env
    ports:
    - "10002:10002"
    image: corda/notary:2.0
    container_name: notary
    volumes:
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Notary/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Notary/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Notary/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Notary/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Notary/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/

  Xxxxx:
    networks:
    - corda
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION: 3.2-corda
    env_file:
    - ./corda_docker.env
    ports:
    - "10007:10002"
    - "10008:10003"
    - "10009:10004"
    - "10048:10048"
    image: corda/xxxxx:2.0
    container_name: xxxxx
    volumes:
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxx/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxx/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxx/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxx/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxx/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/

  Xxxxxx:
    networks:
    - corda
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION: 3.2-corda
    env_file:
    - ./corda_docker.env
    ports:
    - "10010:10002"
    - "10011:10003"
    - "10051:10051"
    - "8888:10004"
    image: corda/xxxxxx:2.0
    container_name: xxxxxx
    volumes:
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxx/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxx/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxx/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxx/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxx/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/


  Xxxxxxx:
    networks:
    - corda
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BUILDTIME_CORDA_VERSION: 3.2-corda
    env_file:
    - ./corda_docker.env
    ports:
    - "10013:10002"
    - "10014:10003"
    - "10015:10004"
    - "10054:10054"
    image: corda/xxxxxxx:2.0
    container_name: xxxxxxx
    volumes:
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxxx/node.conf:/opt/corda/node.conf
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxxx/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxxx/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxxx/certificates/:/opt/corda/certificates/
    - ./java-source/build/nodes/Xxxxxxx/cordapps/:/opt/corda/cordapps/

networks:
  corda:
```

Which changes should I do in order to map correctly the nodes? As you can see, the node is calling itself instead of calling the other peer.

This transaction involves two peers.

Comment: I think your local will alway call localhost with the port and it will automatic route to the mapping that you config, so the error should be the other?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you tried create your nodes by plugin: net.corda.plugins.Cordform.

But for nodes for Docker you should use net.corda.plugins.Dockerform.

[Example for prepare Docker Nodes](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3.0/samples/irs-demo/cordapp/build.gradle#L111)